# Dynamic timeline chart with D3 charts

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, timeline

How can a timeline chart using D3.js can be made dynamic with real time data.

- D3 timeline chart is drawn with a fixed timeline of 12 hours. It reports top running TV program for kids.
- As time passes, chart is receiving real time data from server.
- If a particular channel is top for 5 minutes, the chart shall get updated. This shall be shown as the increasing rectangle size on the timeline chart.
- After a while if top channel ranking is changed, a new value in timeline shall appear.
  [image: Timeline chart with realtime data]

I am not sure how this is achievable using D3. I can draw static predefined data but dynamic i didnt find any option to do.